# SSRS report attachments failed to open

Tags: reporting-services, report, attachment

We have migrated our servers to Cloud (AWS). We are using `SSRS` `2008R2`. We are facing an issue while opening few attachments in the reports ( not all the attachments ).

We get the following error :

> **Server Error in '/OpenAttachments' Application.**
>
> **The remote Server returned an error: (404) Not Found.**
>
> **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details:** System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
>
> **Source Error:**
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> **Stack Trace:**
>
> [WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.]
>      System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +8674060
>      WebApplication1.WebForm1.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\fdsfsdfsdfn\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\OpenAtt.aspx.vb:17
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3178

Most of the attachments are working fine. This is happening with only a few attachments.

Thanks in advance.

Surya

Comment: This seems to be a problem in your *WebApplication1*. Reports in SSRS do not have "attachments".

Comment: The attachments are present and we are able to go to the path and able to access them.

Comment: I guess that you are running a web application that has a web form containing a ReportViewer control that displays an SSRS report. That report might contain hyperlinks to what you call "attachments". But I do not want to guess, I want to read a complete description of the problem in your question. Have you done any analysis on this issue? What is the difference between attachments that do work and that don't? Could it be that the links to the non-working "attachments" still point to old servernames? Or have you forgotten to migrate some of the "attachments"?

Comment: Attachments are links to documents stored on a shared path which are incorporated in the report. we migrated all the files. There are multiple folders in the shared path. In each folder, we have multiple files.Each folder represents attachments of a single report. The problem here is, in one report, we are not able to open one of the links which refers to the files which are stored in the shared path. If I go to that shared path, I am able to see that file. all the links are updated and all the files are present. This is configured in IIS.

Comment: I found that this issue is because of a special character in the file name of the attachment file which is throwing the 404 error from IIS. It has nothing to do with SSRS. I have around 3000 files of that sort. Is there a way out?

Comment: That's what I said in the beginning. It has nothing to do with SSRS.